# Function unbounded on a neighbourhood then limit doesn't exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

I came across a corollary which goes as follows:

Let $D \subset \mathbb R $. If $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb R$  is not bounded on $N(c,\delta)\, \cap \, D$ for some $\delta$ - neighbourhood $N(c,\delta)$ of c, then
$\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ does not exist on $\mathbb R$.

My question is, in this corollary shouldn't this condition of unboundedness apply on every $\delta$ - neighbourhood $N(c,\delta)$ of c.

For example if f(x) = tan(x), and c = $\pi/4$,
D = $ [0,\pi/2) \cup (\pi/2,3\pi/2) $ , then for a $\pi/2$-neigbourhood of $\pi/4$, $N(\pi/4,\pi/2) $.
f is not bounded on the interval

$ N(\pi/4,\pi/2)\, \cap \, D = [0,\pi/2) \cup(\pi/2,3\pi/4) $, which would imply that $\lim_{x \to \pi/4} tan(x)$ doesn't exist. Which is not true

Also, in this corollary how would it be affected if we consider a deleted neighbourhood?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are absolutely correct - this condition would need to hold for *every* $\delta$ in order to sufficiently break the limit.